# What is the right-click menu?

Tags: menu, error-handling

Sorry if this is a basic question, but I am new to Ubuntu. I am receiving an error in the top bar saying, "An error occurred, please run Package Manager from the right-click menu or..."

I don't know where the right-click menu is.

Comment: Where do you see this ?

Comment: Upper right hand corner. I see a sign that looks like a Do not Enter sign with a red circle and a horizontal white bar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click the sign that looks like a do not enter sign. This is what's called the right-click menu (for the package manager). If you look in the list of items and messages, there should be a Package Manager link.

I've had this problem before and opening the package manager won't do a lot to fix it but it can help.

If you still get the message after opening the package manager, open a terminal and enter the following commands (these worked for me):

```
sudo apt-get update
```

This will (as any command where you use sudo) ask for your password.
Enter it and press enter.

Next, enter:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

This probably will fix the problem. It happens quite a lot when updates get stuck.

Comment: I don't see anything about the package manager in there. There's just the error message and three options "Show updates", "Show notifications", and "Preferences"

Comment: Also, I entered the commands, but the do not enter sign is still there.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have a corrupt entry in your repository. In order to fix this follow the below instructions.

1)Open the terminal using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>

2) type: `sudo apt-get check`

This checks for broken repositories.

3) type: `sudo apt-get update`

This updates the repository file after the above fix.

You may need to restart the computer after doing this for the error to disappear, but it should fix the issue. Any problems, let me know. :)

Answer (score 0):

The fix is very simple. Open the terminal and run the command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and then restart your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Another good solution is to restart your computer which would usually fix the problem. It gives an opportunity for your repository list to refresh. Try it and say how it goes.